# java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, okhttp

Calling one of our in-house web services seems to be giving the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{webservicessandbox.xxx.com:443, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=174.143.185.13 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
```

From what I've seen elsewhere, this is being pointed to as a server issue, but we're not seeing this problem when the WS is being called in browser or in IOS. I've used both OkHTTP and a manual HTTPUrlConnection implementation and it hasn't seemed to make any difference. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
OKHttp:
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiToken)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                    .url(uri)
                    .build();
HTTPURLConnection:
            URL myURL = new URL(uri);
            HttpsURLConnection myConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
            myConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            myConnection.setDoOutput(false);
            myConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            myConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiToken);
            myConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
            int respCode = myConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of proxy?

Comment: Do remote server expect 2 way ssl (requests client certificate)?

Comment: As far as I'm able to tell this may be a problem only applicable to my Android emulation. When I switched off of emulation and onto a physical device I appear to not be having issues with this error occurring any longer. I still don't understand why this would stop working when previously I was able to use the emulator fine. Potentially an issue with an update to the emulator at some point?

Answer (score 12):

Please try the potential solutions (in my opinion) below:

1- Try to use `retryOnConnectionFailure(true)` as below:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .build();
```

2- Try to add: `request.addHeader("Connection","close")` (most cases this is the solution, respecting to Kartik's answer.)

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiToken)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Connection","close")
                    .url(uri)
                    .build();
```

3- Please increase the response time of the server (set it as high as possible) and try again.

Also see: [OkHTTP Websocket: Unexpected end of steam on Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161398/okhttp-websocket-unexpected-end-of-steam-on-connection)

Answer (score 2):

Both the client and server needs to close the connection once they are finished.

In your OkHttp request builder, add this line: `.header("Connection", "close")`.

Also check the network tab of your browser inspector to see which headers the browser is sending. Match those headers in your code and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This error `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` is related to server. A possible reason could be, the server is shut down.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but no, I'm able to consistently call the services using other devices.

Comment: is it a device speci9?

Comment: This is not an error, it is a TLS cipher suite.